# PowerAutomate + Dataverse - Listing Rows that Have Length Longer Than X

Tags: odata, power-automate, dataverse

This seems pretty straight forward, I don't think I need to do much explaining here. I'm just looking for phone numbers that have 10 digits in them and I want to slip a "+" into them so they work with our automations and with customer lookups based on phone number.

[image: What I'm trying to Do]

I also tried making a formula column in DV that detects if the main phone is 10 digits but they didn't like that
[image: Formula column]

Answer (score 1):

`length` is not a valid operator for the `Filters rows` parameter (it requires OData syntax). There is a syntax to perform a search based on the position but I don't remember the syntax right now and I don't remember if it can be used in OData or requires the usage of `Fetch Xml Query`.

Regarding the formula column, the operator should be `Len`, you can find the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-len